# Angular ng-repeat preventDefault alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using **library for input type options**. 
I display it in list with checkbox.

The problem is whenever I click on input select options i'm also selecting 
checkbox. I decided to using event.preventDefault() but it breaks select options and I have two selectbox opened.
So I cannot use event.preventDefault(), do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Here is example but without custom library for select options.
http://jsfiddle.net/ufbmsabr/

Comment: What you try to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent checking checkbox when I click on select options. For some reason I cannot use event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont now what you try to achieve but I tried to refactor your codes like in this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scgcf4u3/). You should refactor your DOM construction. I think your problem is related to a wrong DOM hierarchy. I so no point for check/uncheck the checkbox by clicking the parent `p` element. So, whatever this will work for you:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <p ng-repeat="role in roles" ng-click="check(role)">
      <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.id" ng-model="role.check">                 {{role.text}}
      <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-click="log()">
        <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
      <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-click="log()">
        <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </p>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
angular.module("DemoApp", ["checklist-model"])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.optionClicked = false;
    $scope.check = function (role) {
      $timeout(function () {
        if (!$scope.optionClicked) {
          role.check = !role.check
        }
      }, 50);
    }

    $scope.log = function () {
      $scope.optionClicked = true;
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.optionClicked = false;
      }, 100);
    }

    $scope.roles = [{
      check: true,
      id: 1,
      text: 'guest'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'user'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      text: 'customer'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      text: 'admin'
    }];

  });
```

Comment: Im trying to prevent checking checkbox when I click on select options. For some reason I cannot use event.preventDefault()

Comment: @User_111 In this solution the checkbox got not checked when you select an option. Please give more information about what you try to achieve.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uv0Layaf/ When you click on <p> it should check checkbox but not when you are clicking in select options

Comment: OK, why do you want this functionality?

Comment: It looks like a bug when I click on select and it check the checkbox. I cant use event preventDefault in this case because I use custom directive instead of regular select options and I cannot close select on focus next select..

Comment: @User_111 Nono, why do you want to check/uncheck the checkbox by clicking the whole <p>?

Comment: Thats true, but this is how all rest components works. So do you think is there any other solution than checking event target class for example?

Comment: I make it work for you please check my answer. Does it work for you? But you still did not answer my question. Why do you want to check/uncheck the selectbox by clicking the whole parent p element?

Comment: Yes it works but I will try with event target I think.  Answer: this is a feature of layout :)

Comment: @User_111 glad to help ya.

Answer (score 0):

**I am not able to understand what you are trying to achieve**

What I understood is you are selecting an option in one select bar and another one is also get opened with the same value.

**Solution:-** What I found is you are using the same model for both the select bar: *data.singleSelect*

```
 <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
```

This is causing issue. Use the different name in *ng-model* for both the select bar. It will solve the issue.